# Simple Loop In Assembly (Branch Unconditionally)

Tags: loops, assembly

I'm trying to create a simple loop in assembly to perform an instruction until a certain condition is met. For example, I want to implement this C code in assembly:

```
int compute_sum(int n)
{
 i = 2;
 sum = 0;
 while(i <= n)
 {
 sum = sum + i;
 i = i + 4;
 }
}
```

The outline I made for myself is this:

```
/ ADD (compute sum)
/ Increment to keep track of # times passed through loop
/ SNA (skip if difference between user input and number is < 0)
/ BUN xxx (repeat)
```

I read in user input and have the decimal representation, but do not know the address that should follow BUN so that the instructions are repeated. These are all done in simple computer instructions

Comment: Which assembly language do you use?

Comment: In assembly language, you can have labels that you define yourself for instructions or data. You branch or jump to the label you want to form a loop.

Comment: The question seems to be asking for the syntax for labels in [Mano machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mano_machine) assembler!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to practice getting into the correct mindset by using C without structured conditions (ie using labels and gotos):

```
i = 2;
sum = 0;
loop:
if  (i > n) goto finished;
sum = sum + i;
i = i + 4;
goto loop;
finished:
```

This is perfectly valid C (albeit archaic) but shows what you need to do at the simplest level. Compare i with n and branch to finished if greater and branch unconditionally to the loop level.

If the assembler language you are using does not have an unconditional branch then you can set the flag and branch (eg SEC, BCS loop) or count on the idea that i will not overflow and when you add 4, branch on no overflow - just make sure it doesn't fail catastrophically if this is not the case.

So, in assembler (which shares the label syntax), you would have:

```
loop:
cmp   i, n      ; Or register equivelents
bgt   finished
    ....
add   i, 4
bvc   loop
finished:
```